# Whats wrong with my rig?

Tags: rigging

https://mega.nz/#!C3hinCwa!h_3F6_WkF8-Cm4iLqbBorElmumhXKJnDnelBMFN3X_0

There's the blend file. I need it to bend backward in sort of a 'U' shape, but it bends and contorts in odd ways. I need to get this done asap as a client needed something done in 2 days, so I'm having to learn blender rigging on the spot. Anyone who can tell me what I need to do would be a hero. I tried turning on preserve volume which keeps the mesh from changing sizes, but it doesnt bend back as much as I need it to.

Comment: Hi. A blend is good, but ideally blend files should be supplemental to good question content, e.g. a description of how you imported them and screenshots of the result. We ideally want people to be able to answer the question (or see if they have the same problem) as easily as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, radical solution, follow these steps:

[image]

Comment: That caused the top two pieces to stop pulling the mesh at all unfortunately.

Comment: I've edited, so please try this method

Comment: It worked, thanks! I guess my first error was having weights on the bottom bone when I can just rotate that from the normal geometry anyway. The second one doesnt appear to need to be weight painted though. Is there a reason for that?